# How to mark particular dates in react-calender

Tags: reactjs

How do I highlight specific Dates in [react-calendar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-calendar)?

This is my code:

```
<Calendar
    style={{ height: 500 }}
    onChange={this.onChange}
    value={this.state.date}
    tileContent={d}
    hover={'2020-02-29'}

    tileDisabled={({ date }) => date.getDay() === 0}

    minDate={
        new Date()
    }
></Calendar>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**I solved the issue........I modified my code**

*CSS code*

```
  .highlight {
                color:red;
             }
```

*I have created an array of multiple dates*

```
const mark = [
      '04-03-2020',
      '03-03-2020',
      '05-03-2020'
  ]
```

*And finally, the calendar will look like this*

```
<Calendar
    style={{ height: 500 }}
    onChange={this.onChange}
    value={this.state.date}
    tileClassName={({ date, view }) => {
      if(mark.find(x=>x===moment(date).format("DD-MM-YYYY"))){
       return  'highlight'
      }
    }}


    tileDisabled={({ date }) => date.getDay() === 0}

    /*maxDate={new Date(2020, 1, 0)}</div>*/
     minDate={
      new Date()
    }
  >
</Calendar>
```

**Output**
[image]

Comment: I would warn that this is a o(n^2) operation and the array should be changed into a hash set `marks = new Set(['04-03-2020', '03-03-2020', '05-03-2020', ect...])`, and instead of using `marks.find(...)` o(n), you can use `marks.has(...)` o(1). So as you add more marked days the performance will not decrease.

Comment: and don't forget to remove the "x=>x===" part. ;D

Answer (score 2):

You are using react-calendar. You can highlight a date very easily.

1. create a class `highlight` (name can be anything).
2. Import that style file (.css or .scss)
3. It have a props called `tileClassName`. Send a callback like below.

   ```
       <Calendar
         tileClassName={({ date, view }) => {
          // date will return every date visible on calendar and view will view type (eg. month)
          if(// your_condititon ){
            return 'highlight'; // your class name
           }

         }}
         onChange={this.onChange}
         value={this.state.date}
       />
   ```

Comment: want to make some dates as highlight

Comment: Yes as I posted above, just check if the date === 'your_date' then return the class. It will highlight the date.

Comment: No, it's not working for me. can you give me one example for highlight 23,24,25 dates of March 2020, is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a common way to find out how to adjust styles with some libs which you are not familiar with.

If you look at the DOM tree, you would find each date button have `class` like below

```html
<button class="react-calendar__tile react-calendar__month-view__days__day ...">
...
</button>
```

By change the style of it, we find that's the element we want to handle.

[image]

Notice the className **`react-calendar__tile`**

If we checkout their [document](https://github.com/wojtekmaj/react-calendar) by searching that class name's `tile`. You would find:

> **tileClassName**
> Class name(s) that will be applied to a given calendar item (day on month view, month on year view and so on).

By providing css class to it, you can customize your styles.

For example, make it blue

```
<Calendar
  tileClassName="content"
  ...
/>
```

```css
.content {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: blue;
}
```

[image]

You can try it yourself here

[image: Edit affectionate-darwin-fjp3o]

Answer (score 1):

This will helps you.Working code [source code](https://codesandbox.io/s/event-scheduling-app-0jxuy)

Demo:[evenfy](https://0jxuy.csb.app/)

[image]

Code:

```
dateArray=[{date:"2021-06-11T09:47:17.456000Z",colorName: "pink"},{date:"2021-06-12T09:47:17.456000Z",colorName: "blue"}.{date:"2021-06-16T09:47:17.456000Z",colorName: "blue"}]


  <Calendar
    tileClassName={({ activeStartDate, date, view }) => this.setClass(date)}
  />



setClass = (date) => {
const dateobj =
  dateArray.find((x) => {
    return (
      date.getDay() === new Date(x.date).getDay() &&
      date.getMonth() === new Date(x.date).getMonth() &&
      date.getDate() === new Date(x.date).getDate()
    );
  });
return dateobj ? dateobj.colorName : "";}
```

Comment: Please add the code for your solution directly to the post (it's fine to link as well, but paste the code in the answer also). It is also helpful to explain why your solution works and how you solved the problem.